# Get the sum of each column, with recursive values in each cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given a parameter `p`, be any float or integer.

For example, let `p=4`

| time | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Numbers | a1 | a1*(0.5)^(1/p)^(2-1) | a1*(0.5)^(1/p)^(2-1) | a1*(0.5)^(1/p)^(3-1) | a1*(0.5)^(1/p)^(4-1) |
| Numbers | nan | a2 | a2*(0.5)^(1/p)^(3-2) | a2*(0.5)^(1/p)^(4-2) | a2*(0.5)^(1/p)^(5-2) |
| Numbers | nan | nan | a3 | a3*(0.5)^(1/p)^(4-3) | a3*(0.5)^(1/p)^(5-3) |
| Numbers | nan | nan | nan | a4 | a4*(0.5)^(1/p)^(5-4) |
| Number | nan | nan | nan | nan | a5 |
| Final Results | a1 | sum of column 2 | sum of column 3 | sum of column 4 | sum of column 5 |

Numbers like a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,...,at is given, our goal is to find the `Final Results`. Combining the answer provided by `mozway`, I wrote the following function which works well. It is a `matrix` way to solve the problem.

```
def hl(p,column):
    a = np.arange(len(copy_raw))
    factors = (a[:,None]-a)
    factors = np.where(factors<0, np.nan, factors)
    inter = ((1/2)**(1/p))**factors
    copy_raw[column] = np.nansum(copy_raw[column].to_numpy()*inter, axis=1)
```

However, I don't think this method will work well if we are dealing with large dataframe. Are there any better way to fix the problem? (In this case, faster = better.)

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: I don't know how to write a function like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a place where people write code for you for free. You _can_ ask homework questions, but you should provide the code you wrote in an attempt to solve it and explain what exactly is wrong with it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: Sorry, I did not say my code is too long to show, especially for that one-line for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your number of rows is not too large, you can achieve this with numpy broadcasting:

First create a 2D array of factors:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))
factors = (a[:,None]-a)
factors = np.where(factors<0, np.nan, factors)
# array([[ 0., nan, nan, nan, nan],
#        [ 1.,  0., nan, nan, nan],
#        [ 2.,  1.,  0., nan, nan],
#        [ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0., nan],
#        [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Then map to your data and sum:

```
df['number2'] = np.nansum(df['number'].to_numpy()*(1/2)**factors, axis=1)
```

example output:

```
   Index       Time  number  number2
0      0  1997-WK01       1   1.0000
1      1  1997-WK02       2   2.5000
2      2  1997-WK03       3   4.2500
3      3  1997-WK04       2   4.1250
4      4  1997-WK05       4   6.0625
```

intermediate:

```
df['number'].to_numpy()*(1/2)**factors

# array([[1.    ,    nan,    nan,    nan,    nan],
#        [0.5   , 2.    ,    nan,    nan,    nan],
#        [0.25  , 1.    , 3.    ,    nan,    nan],
#        [0.125 , 0.5   , 1.5   , 2.    ,    nan],
#        [0.0625, 0.25  , 0.75  , 1.    , 4.    ]])
```